# Yii2 and Bootstrap5 - Problems with binding the correct css Files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

i have installed the bootstrap5-exentsion on my Yii-Application. That works fine. But the generated Html-Files binding always the wrong Bootstrap-Version.

I have in my web/assets Folder two different Folders with the Bootstrap 4-Version and the Bootstrap5-Version. But there will always binding only the Boostrap4-Version.

I cleared the Yii Cash with Yii::$app->cache->flush();

Now i have first the Bootstrap5-CSS binding in the header and second the Bootstrap4-CSS binding.

```html
<link href="/basic/web/assets/e6da07ad/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/basic/web/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/basic/web/css/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/basic/web/assets/35517640/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there any other configuration necessary?

Thanks for your answer...

Greetings
SH

Comment: Do you need B4 installed at all?

Comment: The bootstrap4 link is probably added because some AssetBundles that your app uses depends on it. Those may be either your bundles or bundles of some 3rd party widgets. For example widgets from Kartik's extensions depends on bootstrap but allows you to set what version of bootstrap they should use.